# Return google maps autocomplete predictions to method that calls it

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a javascript method `addressAutocomplete` that's called whenever there's a change on an input field. Inside it I call a google maps method to get predictions based on the current input.

My problem is that I want my `addressAutocomplete` method to return the predictions, and I can't find a way to accomplish this. What would be the best way to do this?

My code (the return isn't working)

```
var addressAutocomplete = function(input) {
  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  return service.getQueryPredictions({ input: input }, predictionsCallback);
};

function predictionsCallback(predictions, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }

  return predictions;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best way of doing this, but for now this is how I got it working. Please let me know if you have a better solution to this problem.

```
var addressPredictions;

var addressAutocomplete = function(input) {
  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: input }, predictionsCallback);

  return addressPredictions;
};

function predictionsCallback(predictions, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) return;

  addressPredictions = predictions;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently get `undefined`, right? The problem is you're trying to return values from asynchronous operations, which won't work. You don't have access to `predictions` until `getQueryPredictions` invokes the callback function, and you can't return a value from a callback function. `service.getQueryPredictions` doesn't return a value, it just invokes the callback function when the async operation is done.

I'm not sure I can help you further without more context (such as where `addressAutocomplete` is getting invoked or registered. What you need is to either use the continuous passing style or possibly use promises. Here's a sketch of what you might need to do:

```
var addressAutocomplete = function(input) {
  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  //you can't return this line because it's an async function
  service.getQueryPredictions({ input: input }, function (predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
    }
    //again, we can't return a value here, but we can pass it to another function!
    // this is not exactly how you should do it, just an example
    // Only stringifying it here for example, since I don't know the shape of the predictions object
    $('.autocomplete-results').text(JSON.stringify(predictions));
  });
};
```

edit: just adding the text to the DOM. Here, I'm grabbing the element I want to update with jquery, then setting its text to the stringified predictions object. I don't know what predictions looks like, but you'll probably want to define a helper function to parse and format the text and then update the DOM.

Comment: I added the method that calls `addressAutocomplete` to my question

Comment: OK, so it still looks like you aren't yet doing anything with the results in your keypress callback. First, a quick and dirty test would be to `console.log` the predictions to make sure you're getting something back that you can use. Once you've established that, you'll probably want to post it to the DOM with jQuery. I'll amend my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I can't use it that way. I need to have the predictions returned from `addressAutocomplete`.

Comment: I got it working using global variables, but i don't know if it's the best or even a good way of doing this.